# MSRP vs FTP

Tags: ftp, protocols

What is difference between MSRP(Message Session Relay Protocol) protocol and FTP protocol ( in terms of transferring files)

Comment: Are they related? (I do not think so.) Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Message Session Relay Protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking in terms of transferring files.

ftp, or [File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp), is designed for transferring files from a dedicated server.

msrp, or [Message Session Relay Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Session_Relay_Protocol), is used for "transmitting a series of related instant messages".  This can be used to transfer files to another user.

The big difference I can see is that ftp requires a server, while msrp is user to user, or peer to peer.

Answer (score 3):

What precisely do you mean by "operationally"?

[FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP) is a protocol for transferring files over IP.

[MSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Session_Relay_Protocol) is a protocol for sending instant messages.

They are not at all alike. You might as well ask what the operational differences between dogs and [TheTXI](http://www.ponyoverflow.com) are.

Comment: Well, for one, most dogs aren't obsessively fixated on ponies.

Comment: @Pesto: One could say the same of FTP.